# How to extract a particular attribute from instance of Win32_PnPEntity?

Tags: python, winapi, wmi, pywin32, wql

```
def getPnpDeviceInfo():
    c = wmi.WMI()
    wql = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Manufacturer != 'Microsoft' AND NOT PNPDeviceID LIKE 'ROOT\\%'"
    print ("All physical PNP devices")
    for J in c.query(wql):
    print(J)
```

This function (the query) typically returns all physical PNP devices, here is an output sample :

```
instance of Win32_PnPEntity
{
Caption = "ACPI Lid";
ClassGuid = "{4d36e97d-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}";
ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0;
ConfigManagerUserConfig = FALSE;
CreationClassName = "Win32_PnPEntity";
Description = "ACPI Lid";
DeviceID = "ACPI\\PNP0C0D\\2&DABA3FF&3";
HardwareID = {"ACPI\\PNP0C0D", "*PNP0C0D"};
Manufacturer = "(Standard system devices)";
Name = "ACPI Lid";
PNPDeviceID = "ACPI\\PNP0C0D\\2&DABA3FF&3";
Status = "OK";
SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
SystemName = "SUSDUTTA-LAP";
};
```

Question is, if I want to extract just the "PNPDeviceID" of the instance, how to do so in python, without changing the WQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, figured in the [WMI python doc](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/wmi.html). The WQL returns the answer as a list, and there is a factory method "`__getattr__(self,'attribute_name'_)`" which returned the data using specific attribute name.