# How to get USB device "Manufacturer" field through WinAPI?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, com, pywin32

I am trying to get the Manufacturer field of a USB device I have plugged-in.
The "Properties" dialog of the device in Windows reports:

```
Device description: USB Serial Converter
Device type: Universal Serial Bus controllers
```

USB tools like [FT_Prog](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Utilities.htm#FT_PROG) and [Microsoft USBView](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Utilities.htm#MicrosoftUSBView) report that the "iManufacturer" device descriptor field of my device is set to "MyCompanyFoo".

So far, using the **pywin32** package, I was able to get the VendorID, DeviceID and SerialNumber of the device:

```
import win32com.client
wmi = win32com.client.GetObject("winmgmts:")

for usb in wmi.InstancesOf("Win32_UsbHub"):
    print 'DeviceID: ' + str(usb.DeviceID)
```

However the [`Win32_UsbHub`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394506(v=vs.85).aspx) structure does not contain the "Manufacturer" attribute.

I tried instead to use the [`Win32_USBController`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394504(v=vs.85).aspx) WMI structure which does have this attribute:

```
for usb in wmi.InstancesOf ("Win32_UsbController"):
    print 'Manufacturer: ' + str(usb.Manufacturer)
```

but it's output is incorrect for my purposes (it should be "MyCompanyFoo"):

```
Manufacturer: Intel
Manufacturer: Intel
Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
```

[`Win32_DiskDrive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx) WMI class prints the same wrong output.

I know of alternative solutions for this task like "PyUSB" with "libusb1.0" backend, but
these require installing a driver dependency which I can't afford.

Comment: I am not so familiar with Windows USB API's but are you sure the manufacturer information is available? Sometimes the devices return id of the actual manufacturer or for example the USB chip vendor instead of the brand the device is sold under. Sometimes some information is completely missing. This page tells you what information you may expect, the string descriptors are not mandatory: http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#DeviceDescriptors ... perhaps you need to read the vendorId and convert that to a string yourself?

Comment: @diidu Thanks for the useful link. I'm actually using a utility [FT_Prog](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Utilities.htm#FT_PROG) to manually set the "iManufacturer" and "iProduct" fields mentioned in your link on my device. So the information is definitely there. I don't want to convert the VendorID to a name, because the manufacturer is someone other than FTDI--the vendor.

Comment: Keep in mind that "the info is definitely there" could be because FT_Prog is converting vendor ids into vendor names - which is what diidu is suggesting you do. I suggest downloading USBVIEW and see what it says about your device.

Comment: Have you tried WMI like in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911001/how-to-extract-a-particular-attribute-from-instance-of-win32-pnpentity)?

Comment: @user2460798 I'm sure the info is there because I set the "iManufacturer" field myself to my company's name, using FT_Prog. Indeed, USBView confirms this.

Comment: @Mark I wasn't even aware of the WMI Python package, thanks! I will try to get it to work